# How to set MSBuild to take compilation or build order from solution file

Tags: c++, msbuild, devenv

We have set the parallel execution count to 1 so that all the projects will build one after other.In the Visual Studio settings.

With below command from Devenv.exe we are able to compile the solution correctly.

call vcvarsall.bat x86_amd64
devenv /Build "Release|x64" "w:/Frameworks/Frameworks.sln"

But with MSBuild, with below command, the solution is failing to compile, when I cross check the log, the order of compilation of projects is not correct, not taking from solution file.

call vcvarsall.bat x86_amd64
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" "W:\Frameworks\Frameworks.sln" /t:build /fl /flp:logfile=Frameworks.log;verbosity=normal /p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64 /m:1

Any suggestion, how to fix set msbuild to compile only from order mentioned in solution file.

Answer (score 0):

Open your solution in VisualStudio, on the solution explorer right click the solution name and look for "Project Dependencies..." and/or "Project Build Order..."

The UI is self explanatory, so configure as required, save all and try the MsBuild command again.

[image]

Comment: The build order is correct only  . that's why it is working with devenv.
But with msbuild it is not picking the order present in solution file

Comment: That's why I said "And/Or" for dependencies and build order. The build order may look correct in VS, but if you still have errors due to the order, you may want to force some project dependencies, that will be respected by msbuild.